# tidy - fill NA in columns with value two cells above the "NA" cells

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a tidy dataset with an slightly unusual structure in some columns. The data structure is outlined in an example below - there is a header row containing all the key information, with records for each bank (rightmost column) in the rows below but with NA instead of carrying forward the key information. I would like to use tidy::fill to carry forward the last non-NA observation, however for one column there is usually another entry below the header row (see example). Is it possible to use fill to choose the last but one non-NA value, such that I can fill it in with the correct information? Thanks for any help!

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(amount = c(2000, NA, NA, NA, 2500, NA, NA, NA),
       amount_thismkt = c(1000, NA, NA, NA, 2500, NA, NA, NA),
       nation = c("United States", NA, NA, NA, "China", NA, NA, NA),
       purpose = c("Refinancing", "GCP", NA, NA, "GCP", "Refinancing", NA, NA),
       bank = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "E", "F", "B"))

df
# # A tibble: 8 × 5
#   amount amount_thismkt nation        purpose     bank 
#    <dbl>          <dbl> <chr>         <chr>       <chr>
# 1   2000           1000 United States Refinancing A    
# 2     NA             NA NA            GCP         B    
# 3     NA             NA NA            NA          C    
# 4     NA             NA NA            NA          D    
# 5   2500           2500 China         GCP         A    
# 6     NA             NA NA            Refinancing E    
# 7     NA             NA NA            NA          F    
# 8     NA             NA NA            NA          B    
df %>% fill(amount, amount_thismkt, nation)
# # A tibble: 8 × 5
#   amount amount_thismkt nation        purpose     bank 
#    <dbl>          <dbl> <chr>         <chr>       <chr>
# 1   2000           1000 United States Refinancing A    
# 2   2000           1000 United States GCP         B    
# 3   2000           1000 United States NA          C    
# 4   2000           1000 United States NA          D    
# 5   2500           2500 China         GCP         A    
# 6   2500           2500 China         Refinancing E    
# 7   2500           2500 China         NA          F    
# 8   2500           2500 China         NA          B
```

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you are trying to fill? Is it all of the columns with NAs? 
It is unclear to me what you mean by: "the last but one non-NA value".
Perhaps if you could make a dataframe of what you want the result to look like it would be a bit easier to determine what you're goal is.

Comment: Please share your expected output thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure if you want to *remove* the last value, and just fill with the first value, or just leave the last value in place. To do the first, you can do:

```
df |> 
  mutate(purpose = ifelse(!is.na(lag(purpose)), NA, purpose)) |>
  fill(amount, amount_thismkt, nation, purpose)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 5
  amount amount_thismkt nation        purpose     bank 
   <dbl>          <dbl> <chr>         <chr>       <chr>
1   2000           1000 United States Refinancing A    
2   2000           1000 United States Refinancing B    
3   2000           1000 United States Refinancing C    
4   2000           1000 United States Refinancing D    
5   2500           2500 China         GCP         A    
6   2500           2500 China         GCP         E    
7   2500           2500 China         GCP         F    
8   2500           2500 China         GCP         B
```

To do the second, you can do:

```
df |> 
  fill(amount, amount_thismkt, nation) |>
  mutate(purpose = ifelse(is.na(purpose), first(purpose), purpose), .by = nation)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 5
  amount amount_thismkt nation        purpose     bank 
   <dbl>          <dbl> <chr>         <chr>       <chr>
1   2000           1000 United States Refinancing A    
2   2000           1000 United States GCP         B    
3   2000           1000 United States Refinancing C    
4   2000           1000 United States Refinancing D    
5   2500           2500 China         GCP         A    
6   2500           2500 China         Refinancing E    
7   2500           2500 China         GCP         F    
8   2500           2500 China         GCP         B
```

Comment: Apologies for not being clearer, but the first option is exactly what I intended! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a solution using `fill()`, but this question is interesting as it is actually one of the few examples, where a `for`-loop is necessary in R.

So, I create a small helper function here that takes in a vector and goes through the elements (starting at element 2). If the current element `i` is `NA` then it inputs the element before that.

You can then apply this function to all columns of your dataframe at the same time - only thing you need is the dataframe to be sorted correctly.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(amount = c(2000, NA, NA, NA, 2500, NA, NA, NA),
             amount_thismkt = c(1000, NA, NA, NA, 2500, NA, NA, NA),
             nation = c("United States", NA, NA, NA, "China", NA, NA, NA),
             purpose = c("Refinancing", "GCP", NA, NA, "GCP", "Refinancing", NA, NA),
             bank = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "E", "F", "B"))


fill_in_last_non_NA <- function(x){
    for (i in seq_along(x)[-1]){
        if (is.na(x[i])) x[i] <- x[i-1]
    }
    x
}

df |>
    mutate(across(everything(), fill_in_last_non_NA))

# A tibble: 8 × 5
amount amount_thismkt nation        purpose     bank 
<dbl>          <dbl> <chr>         <chr>       <chr>
1   2000           1000 United States Refinancing A    
2   2000           1000 United States GCP         B    
3   2000           1000 United States GCP         C    
4   2000           1000 United States GCP         D    
5   2500           2500 China         GCP         A    
6   2500           2500 China         Refinancing E    
7   2500           2500 China         Refinancing F    
8   2500           2500 China         Refinancing B
```

Comment: What is the difference between what you have and using fill ? Ie `fill(df)`?

Comment: @Onyambu correct me if I'm wrong but it seems `fill(df)` doesn't do anything - for me, `sum(is.na(fill(df)))` equals 22? But I get the idea

Comment: @Mark sorry, i believe `fill(df, everything())`. I am on a phone. cannot test code

Comment: @Onyambu, I cannot speak for what `fill()` is doing. The function here fills every `NA` with the last prior non`NA`value, if there is one.

Comment: Just pointing out that You are already using tidyverse. There is a function called `fill`. you could directly use `fill(df, everything())` no need of writing the custom function. If you were in base R, then you could write a custome function but with indexing rather than for-loop

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to carry down the first non-`NA` value in `purpose`?

```r
df %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(!is.na(nation))) %>%
  mutate(purpose = coalesce(purpose, na.omit(purpose)[1])) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  fill(amount, amount_thismkt, nation)
# # A tibble: 8 × 6
#   amount amount_thismkt nation        purpose     bank    grp
#    <dbl>          <dbl> <chr>         <chr>       <chr> <int>
# 1   2000           1000 United States Refinancing A         1
# 2   2000           1000 United States GCP         B         1
# 3   2000           1000 United States Refinancing C         1
# 4   2000           1000 United States Refinancing D         1
# 5   2500           2500 China         GCP         A         2
# 6   2500           2500 China         Refinancing E         2
# 7   2500           2500 China         GCP         F         2
# 8   2500           2500 China         GCP         B         2
```

Comment: Apologies for not being clearer, I intended to both carry down the first value and replace the second value with the first. Thanks!